# SignalR with Python websockets return 503

Tags: python, websocket, signalr

I have created simplest Hub in ASP.NET Core and pushed it into Azure containing below piece of code:

```
public class TestHub: Hub
{
}

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   endpoints.MapControllers();
   endpoints.MapHub<TestHub>("/testHub");
});
```

To validate hub is working and client has possibility to retrieve messages I have created console application using Microsoft.SignalR client library:

```
var url = "{baseUrl}/testHub";

var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .WithUrl(url)
      .WithAutomaticReconnect()
      .Build();

connection.On("OpenDoors", () =>
{
   Console.Write("Message");
});

await connection.StartAsync();
```

With above solution I am able to retrieve messages from the SignalR deployed to Azure.

Now I am trying to do the same using Python and its websockets.

To achieve this I do negotiation:

```
negotiation = requests.post('https://{url}/testHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=0', verify=False).json()
```

which returns me the correct values. I am trying now to do the handshake:

```
connectionId = negotiation['connectionId'])

async with websockets.connect('wss://{url}/testHub?id={connectionId }')
```

There I retrieve an error:

> websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket
> connection: HTTP 503

What do I miss?